# java - add length constraint to regex

Tags: java, regex, alphanumeric

i need a regex to match alphanumeric ASCII strings of length 11. currently i'm using this regex: `^\p{ASCII}*$`.

is there a way to add a length constraint to it?

Comment: k it was actually a pretty stupid question and i found the answer after about 5 mins on google but thanks for the quick replies... +1 all around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
^\p{ASCII}{0,11}$
```

this means you have up to 11 characters.

If you need only 11. you use:

```
^\p{ASCII}{11}$
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the `{n,m}` quantifier. For example, `^\p{ASCII}{11}$`. Though I don't know what `\p{ASCII}` is, try `[[:ascii:]]` or `[[:alpha:]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use (I suspect you want at least one character)

```
^\p{ASCII}{1,11}$
```

or if it has to be a length of 11

```
^\p{ASCII}{11}$
```